# array_filter with element modification

Tags: php, array-filter

I'm trying to make a clean array from a string that my users will define.
The string can contain non-valid IDs, spaces, etc. I'm checking the elements using a value object in a callback function for `array_filter`.

```
$definedIds = "123,1234,1243, 12434 , asdf"; //from users panel

$validIds = array_map(
    'trim',
    array_filter(
        explode(",", $definedIds),
        function ($i) {
            try {
                new Id(trim($i));
                return true;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    )
);
```

This works fine, but I'm applying `trim` twice. Is there a better way to do this or a different PHP function in which I can modify the element before keeping it in the returned array?

NOTE: I also could call `array_map` in the first parameter of `array_filter`, but I would be looping through the array twice anyway.

Comment: As a small suggestion, don't make the constructor throw, but instead use a statically defined `Id.isValidId(input)` that you can call, so you don't need to incur memory allocation, symbol table modification, and garbage collection. You're not doing anything with the `Id` object you're creating, so if you're using it just to check if an id is valid, make that a dedicated function you can call.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: why don't you use `str_replace` for removing whitespaces before mapping the array ?

Comment: @BeingSunny it's [123,1234,1243,12434]

Comment: @mim. that's a good idea for this particular case, but still wondering if there is a function using the callback to fill the returned array

Comment: @CarlosAS you may try `array_walk_recursive` then.

Comment: Simply call `preg_split('/,\s*/', $string)` to explode on commas with and without trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you care about performance. If you do, don't use map+filter, but use a plain for loop and manipulate your array in place:

```
$arr = explode(',', $input);

for($i=count($arr)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
  // make this return trimmed string, or false,
  // and have it trim the input instead of doing
  // that upfront before passing it into the function.
  $v = $arr[$i] = Id.makeValid($arr[$i]);

  // weed out invalid ids
  if ($v === false) {
    array_splice($arr, $i, 1);
  }
}

// at this point, $arr only contains valid, cleaned ids
```

Of course, if this is inconsequential code, then trimming twice is *really* not going to make a performance difference, but you can still clean things up:

```
$arr = explode(',', $input);
$arr = array_filter(
  array_map('Id.isValidId', $arr),
  function ($i) {
    return $i !== false;
  }
);
```

In this example we *first* map using that function, so we get an array of ids and `false` values, and then we filter that so that everything that's `false` gets thrown away, rather than first filtering, and then mapping.

(In both cases the code that's responsible for checking validity is in the `Id` class, and it either returns a cleaned id, or `false`)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it by different way but If I were you then I'll do it this way. Here I just used only one **trim**

```
<?php
$definedIds = "123,1234,1243, 12434 , asdf"; //from users panel
function my_filter($b){
    if(is_numeric($b)){
        return true;
    }
}
print '<pre>';
$trimmed = array_map('trim',explode(',',$definedIds));
print_r(array_filter($trimmed,my_filter));
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**Program Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 1234
    [2] => 1243
    [3] => 12434
)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/997812

Comment: This is the same code of my question, you just named the callback function and removed the value object checks...

Comment: @CarlosAS :P Yes you're ri8, I just unconsciously posted the same kind of logic that you already did. See my edit now I just used only one time **trim** inside array_map()